# Which sentence is correct? The one using the, an or no article?

Tags: grammar, american-english, articles

I have a problem with these sentences. which one is correct?and why?

- He studied the role of an/the/ ' extended family in caring for older people.

Comment: There is only one sentence, and it depends on whether he studied a **particular** (an) extended family or **many**, (the) extended family. What does *a zero or null article Ø/Ø'* mean? If you mean *no* article, that is wrong in both cases.

Comment: I have no problem with ***not having an article*** in the cited context (here are plenty of written instances of [***the role of extended family***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22the+role+of+extended+family%22) in Google Books). I've glanced at [this explanation](https://escholarship.org/content/qt2kb4p9r0/qt2kb4p9r0.pdf?t=lb7ioa#:~:text=The%20zero%20and%20null%20articles%20are%20thus%20maximally%20opposed%20in,in%20the%20plural%20count%20form.) of the difference between zero and null articles (apparently they're semantic ***opposites***), but I haven't quite figured it out yet.

Comment: (By which I mean is it syntactically possible to treat *He studied the role of extended family in caring for older people* as featuring BOTH zero and null articles - and if so, do they have clearly-identifiable different meanings / allusions / nuances?)

Comment: Arguably the implication of using ***an*** rather than ***the*** is that the *indefinite* article more readily admits of the possibility that ***not everyone has** an extended family*. The implication of not having either (zero? null?) is that *"**extended family**"* is a well-established concept in the "social science" domain.

Answer (score 0):

The choice depends on what meaning you are trying to convey.

> He studied the role of **an** extended family in caring for older people.

This implies that he studied a particular extended family and how it affected the care of the older people in that "family".

> He studied the role of **the** extended family in caring for older people.

This implies that he studied multiple extended families and collected/correlated his observations into some sort of organized work.

> He studied the role of extended family in caring for older people.

This is similar to the "the" case except that the implication is that he studied the *concept* of "extended family".

(Though it should be noted that the above is just "implications" -- you'd have to read the final report to know if these were on target or not.)

Comment: I interpret "the extended family" as meaning extended families in general.

Comment: "the" implies that the subject which we are talking about is known for both speaker and listener. and we use "a/an" when we talk about Sth in general.  so u mentioned that "This implies that he studied multiple extended families and collected/correlated his observations into some sort of organized work." is this another use of "the"? and as I mentioned "a" is used when we talk about sth in general. but you told "he studied a particular extended family" this is opposite what I knew. may you explain it more?